# neighbourhood of $0$ in the space of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

For a subspace $A \subset \mathbb{C}^n$, define $\lVert f \rVert_A:=\sup \limits_{x \in A} |f(x)|$, where $f$ is a continuous map $\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}$.

Let $\mathbb{C}^n = \bigcup \limits_{i \in I} T_i$ be a compact exhaustion.
We define the locally convex topology on $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ as induced by the norms $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{T_i}$.

Let $X,Y \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be two regions, with $X \subset Y$. Further, assume that $X$ is relatively compact in $Y$. Now my question is:
Why is $\{f \in \mathcal{O}(Y) | \:\lVert f \rVert_X < 1\}$ a neighbourhood of the zero-function in $\mathcal{O}(Y)$ ?

This is a step in the proof of Cor.5.4 in Holomorphic Functions in several complex variables - introduction to the fundamental theory. By Ludger Kaup, Burchard Kaup

which I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, start by giving it a name:
$$U= \{ f \in \mathcal{O} (Y) |\  ||f||_X <1\}$$
Clearly the zero function $0 \in U$.

$X$ is relatively compact in $Y$, this means that $\exists n$ such that $X \subset T_n$.

Since the topology on $\mathcal{O} (Y)$ is induced by the norms of the $T_i$s, you have that $$||\cdot||_{T_n \cap Y} : \mathcal{O} (Y) \to \Bbb R$$
is continuous.

In particular $$V=\{ f \in \mathcal{O} (Y): ||f||_{T_n \cap Y} <1 \}$$
is open in $\mathcal{O} (Y)$ and the zero function belongs to it.

Finally, since $X \subseteq T_n \cap Y$, then $V \subseteq U$: this means that $U$ is a neighbourhood of $0$.

EDIT: for @Balaji sb' comment.

Suppose that for all $n$ the set $X \setminus T_n$ is not empty. Then so is the closure $\overline{ X \setminus T_n}$. But $\overline{ X \setminus T_n}$ is compact. Hence
$$\{ \overline{ X \setminus T_n} \}_n$$ is a decreasing sequence of non-empty compact sets. This means that $$\bigcap_n \overline{ X \setminus T_n} \neq \emptyset$$

Comment: Thanks alot @Crostul, very understandable !

Comment: May i know how $X \subset T_n$ for some $n$ ? Although this is true if $T_n = Cl(B_n(0))$, i  want to understand for general $T_n$.